# Does plyr skip missing levels of a factor [that is the grouping variable]?

Tags: r, plyr, r-factor

Does plyr skip missing levels of a factor [that is the grouping variable]? It's the first of my questions in diagnosing a problem.

I have a dataset where patients are in `strata=rural` or `strata=city`. I want to compare the `age` in `treatment=A` to `treatment=B`.

For example, I am trying to do:

```
ddply(data.c, .(strata), function(x) t.test(age~treatment, data=x, na.rm=TRUE)
```

But it tells me

> Error in t.test.formula(age ~ treatment, data = x, na.rm = TRUE) : 
>     grouping factor must have exactly 2 levels

If I run `factor(data$strata)` and `factor(data$treatment)` I see only two levels, respectively (they are two labels, respectively; that's not a problem, right?).

Does plyr think that NA is a level in the grouping factor? What might be the problem for the error message?

I've been Googling and looking on stackoverflow to answer the question. I'm pretty new to R but I could not find an answer. Any help is much appreciated.

---

So I have some example code. Chase's example worked nicely but when I use my data, I still get the same error.

`dlply(data.c, .(strata), function(x) t.test(age~treatment, data=x, na.rm=TRUE` produced the same error.

I don't understand why this is.

Below is my `data.c`

```
        strata  age treatment
1   1   57.8630136986301    p_3
2   0   52.958904109589 p_3
3   NA  97.2438356164384    p12
4   0   88.2027397260274    p12
5   1   77.5890410958904    p12
6   1   43.9123287671233    p12
7   1   63.5260273972603    p_3
8   1   42.1890410958904    p12
9   0   52.1753424657534    p12
10  1   65.6493150684932    p12
11  0   44.9835616438356    p12
12  1   64.8849315068493    p12
13  1   57.5835616438356    p12
14  0   47.3013698630137    p12
15  0   74.0356164383562    NA
16  0   65.4986301369863    p12
17  1   83.986301369863 p12
18  0   47.4904109589041    p12
19  1   47.8630136986301    p12
20  1   58.8520547945205    p12
21  1   61.3342465753425    p12
22  1   66.841095890411 p12
23  1   55.6383561643836    p12
24  1   52.7178082191781    p12
25  1   71.4630136986301    p12
26  1   NA  p12
27  1   59.2082191780822    p12
28  1   69.8575342465753    p12
29  1   46.7397260273973    p12
30  1   53.5013698630137    p_3
31  1   41.3205479452055    p12
32  0   51.3917808219178    p_3
33  1   47.8684931506849    p12
34  1   87.654794520548 p12
35  0   75.558904109589 p12
36  1   71.2520547945205    p12
37  1   44.9808219178082    p_3
38  1   52  p_3
39  1   54.7643835616438    p_3
40  1   85.6630136986301    p_3
41  1   74.1835616438356    p_3
42  1   56.8684931506849    p_3
43  1   87.572602739726 p_3
44  1   85.0109589041096    p_3
45  1   70.0767123287671    p_3
46  0   47.2328767123288    p12
47  1   63.7972602739726    p12
48  1   85.8054794520548    p12
49  1   67.027397260274 p12
50  1   60.7342465753425    p12
51  0   61.9479452054794    p_3
52  0   86.8712328767123    p12
53  1   87.8219178082192    p12
54  1   49.9424657534247    p12
55  0   83.386301369863 p12
56  1   88.3013698630137    p12
57  1   55.7890410958904    p12
58  1   63.7616438356164    p12
59  1   55.5041095890411    p12
60  1   43.5232876712329    p12
61  1   58.8246575342466    p12
62  0   46.7397260273973    p12
63  0   74.2027397260274    p_3
64  0   51.9205479452055    p_3
65  0   78.1890410958904    p_3
66  0   78.9917808219178    p_3
```

Comment: can you upload the results of dput(data)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`plyr` does treat missing as a separate group for the purposes of grouping variables. Therefore, in your example, there are three groups: `0`, `1`, and `NA`.  You can see which of the groups is throwing an error by adding the `.inform` argument:

```
dlply(data.c, 
      .(strata), 
      function(x) t.test(age~treatment, data=x, na.rm=TRUE), 
      .inform=TRUE)
```

which reports:

```
Error in t.test.formula(age ~ treatment, data = x, na.rm = TRUE) : 
  grouping factor must have exactly 2 levels
Error: with piece 3: 
  strata      age treatment
3     NA 97.24384       p12
```

And in fact there is just one row with `strata` of `NA`, and doing a `t.test` on a single data point (or rather, where all the data points are in the same group) will give the error you see:

```
> t.test(age~treatment, data=data.c[is.na(data.c$strata),], na.rm=TRUE)
Error in t.test.formula(age ~ treatment, data = data.c[is.na(data.c$strata),  : 
  grouping factor must have exactly 2 levels
```

To get around this problem, you can either subset `data.c` in the `dlply` call:

```
dlply(data.c[!is.na(data.c$strata),],
      .(strata), 
      function(x) t.test(age~treatment, data=x, na.rm=TRUE))
```

(which assumes that you know where the problem will be to work around it) and which gives:

```
$`0`

        Welch Two Sample t-test

data:  age by treatment 
t = 0.2653, df = 15.729, p-value = 0.7942
alternative hypothesis: true difference in means is not equal to 0 
95 percent confidence interval:
 -13.41565  17.24792 
sample estimates:
mean in group p_3 mean in group p12 
         64.22896          62.31283 


$`1`

        Welch Two Sample t-test

data:  age by treatment 
t = 0.6606, df = 18.612, p-value = 0.517
alternative hypothesis: true difference in means is not equal to 0 
95 percent confidence interval:
 -6.998471 13.440397 
sample estimates:
mean in group p_3 mean in group p12 
         65.50091          62.27995 


attr(,"split_type")
[1] "data.frame"
attr(,"split_labels")
  strata
1      0
2      1
```

or you can protect the call with error catching. `plyr` provides a convenience wrapper `try_default` for such a purpose.

```
dlply(data.c, 
      .(strata), 
      function(x) try_default(t.test(age~treatment, data=x, na.rm=TRUE),
                              NULL))
```

which gives

```
Error in t.test.formula(age ~ treatment, data = x, na.rm = TRUE) : 
  grouping factor must have exactly 2 levels
$`0`

        Welch Two Sample t-test

data:  age by treatment 
t = 0.2653, df = 15.729, p-value = 0.7942
alternative hypothesis: true difference in means is not equal to 0 
95 percent confidence interval:
 -13.41565  17.24792 
sample estimates:
mean in group p_3 mean in group p12 
         64.22896          62.31283 


$`1`

        Welch Two Sample t-test

data:  age by treatment 
t = 0.6606, df = 18.612, p-value = 0.517
alternative hypothesis: true difference in means is not equal to 0 
95 percent confidence interval:
 -6.998471 13.440397 
sample estimates:
mean in group p_3 mean in group p12 
         65.50091          62.27995 


$`NA`
NULL

attr(,"split_type")
[1] "data.frame"
attr(,"split_labels")
  strata
1      0
2      1
3     NA
```

Note that there are 3 elements to this output including one for `NA` which is set to `NULL` due to the `try_default`.

Comment: Thanks a lot Brian! Those are some really useful tips.

Answer (score 2):

I think you will need to provide us some sample data as I'm not able to duplicate your error. I do get an error about `ddply()` complaining that the following:

```
 Error in list_to_dataframe(res, attr(.data, "split_labels")) : 
  Results must be all atomic, or all data frames
```

This is because the output from `t.test()` is not a data.frame but a list of class `htest`. So simply telling plyr to return a list object instead fixes the problem. If you want to extract a specific value from the list, you can probably get a data.frame back.

Here's how I set up your data:

```
x <- data.frame(strata = sample(letters[1:2], 100, TRUE),
                age = sample(18:65, 100, TRUE),
                treatment = sample(LETTERS[1:2], 100, TRUE))
x[sample(nrow(x), 10, FALSE), "strata"] <- NA
x[sample(nrow(x), 10, FALSE), "treatment"] <- NA
```

Then simply calling function `dlply()` instead works:

```
out <- dlply(x, .(strata), function(x) t.test(age~treatment, data = x, na.rm=TRUE))
```

And to answer your question, yes - plyr seems to treat NA as a valid group, as evidenced by the length and names out the `out` list object:

```
> names(out)
[1] "a"  "b"  "NA"
```

As I said, a better description of you problem may result in a better answer - but hopefully this gets you on the right path.

Comment: Hi Chase, thanks a lot for answering the question. I didn't know about the list thing; that was essential to know. I sort of fixed it. Assume the code was `dlply(y, .(strata), function(x) t.test(age~treatment, data = x, na.rm=TRUE))`. The problem was that `data=x` was wrong; it gave me the errors about not having 2 levels. When I changed it to `data=y`, it gave me the output. What are your thoughts as to why that was?

Comment: @jnam27 - that is a strange error...the way you set up the function, `dlply()` is creating a data.frame named "x" in the anonymous function...so when you call `t.test()` in that function and supply `data = x`, it should work. Do you have another object in your environment named `y`?

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear about that. I made `y` because `x` was both the dataframe and the argument passed in `function`. And after taking a closer look, it did not work. It ran smoothly, but the output was wrong. I guess I still have the same problem about not having two levels for my grouping variable. I tried to elaborate in my edit in the original post above. Any further thoughts?